# Count number of words that have specific letter in specific order

Tags: shell, unix

How can i count number of words that have specific letter in specific order in UNIX

for example

if i want to find number of words that have letter `a` as second character

to be honest i don't know how to do that

Comment: The answer you accepted will have some false positives, because the pattern `/.a/` will match the letter `a` not only as 2nd character, but 3rd, 4th, and so on, too, for example in the words "character", "alphabet", and so on. See my more accurate answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

> `i want to find number of words that have letter a as second character`

You can use `egrep` like this to count these words.

```
s='dabc foo bat cat bar blue red'
egrep -o '\<[A-Za-z]a[^ ]+\>' <<< "$s"|wc -l
       4
```

Comment: This would match the tail of a word which contains `a` somewhere later. You might want to add a word start anchor to the expression, or maybe explore if the `-w` flag would work here.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~/.a/) total=total+1}} END {print total}' file.txt
```

Note the "." to match the first character of the field, so a is the second character

Answer (score 0):

To match the second letter of a word, the pattern should be something like this:

> START_OF_WORD LETTER1 LETTER2 LETTER3 ...

To match the second letter "a", then depending on the tool you need a regular expression like this:

```
\<.a\w*
\b.a\w*
```

That is:

- `\<` (in `grep` and `vi`) or `\b` (in `perl) match the "start of a word"
- `.` is any character, but not that a character following a `\<` will be inevitably a "word character"
- `a` is a literal "a"
- `\w*` is zero or more word characters

Given the sample text:

> hello abc bar xbar ba hello

The 2 words in this set with second letter "a" are "bar" and "ba".

Here are solutions using `grep` and `perl`:

```
s='hello abc bar xbar ba hello'
grep -o '\<.a\w*' <<< "$s" | wc -l
perl -ne 'print map("$_\n", m/\b(.a\w*)/g)' <<< "$s" | wc -l
```

If the tool doesn't support the `\w` or `\<` or `\b` symbols, then you you can replace `\w` with your own definition of "word characters", for example `[a-zA-Z_]`, and to match the beginning of a word you could first split the input to a list of words, which `awk` does by default. A more accurate version of [@user3114046](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3114046/user3114046) solution using `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i ~ /^.a/) c+=1}} END {print c}' <<< "$s"
```